# Superlative, present perfect vs past perfect

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect, superlative-degree

In the following context, can I have present perfect, or do I need to use past perfect?

It was the worst food I'**ve ever eaten** / I **had ever eaten**.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to say. It can be that it's still the worst thing you've ever eaten or it was worse than anything you had tried before the point in time you're talking about.